# Return null rows if not found in where mysql

Tags: mysql

Imagine have a request Like :

```
Select product_id,category, price  FROM mytable
WHERE category IN('fish', 'chips', 'nuggets')
```

But no products_id has a 'chips' category. Then it will return something like:

| Product_id | category | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | fish | 1,3 |
| 001 | nuggets | 1,4 |
| 002 | fish | 4,1 |
| 002 | nuggets | 3,1 |
| 003 | fish | 1,41 |
| 003 | nuggets | 44,1 |

But I want display null for each conditions not found in where conditions:

| Product_id | category | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | fish | 1,3 |
| 001 | nuggets | 1,4 |
| 001 | chips | NULL |
| 002 | fish | 4,1 |
| 002 | nuggets | 3,1 |
| 002 | chips | NULL |
| 003 | fish | 1,41 |
| 003 | nuggets | 44,1 |
| 003 | chips | NULL |

How can I do that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a calendar table approach along with a cross join:

```sql
SELECT p.product_id, c.category, t.price
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT category FROM mytable) c
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT product_id FROM mytable) p
LEFT JOIN mytable t
    ON t.category = c.category AND
       t.product_id = p.product_id
WHERE c.category IN ('fish', 'chips', 'nuggets')
ORDER BY p.product_id, c.category;
```

Comment: It works very well and fast, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with **case when** statement.

```
select product_id,category, case when category in ('fish','chips','nuggets') then price else NULL end as price FROM mytable
```

Comment: It's almost works but if my table contains others category it diplays all of them. Anyways thanks it can be useful a day aha